# Adding a wordpress user to Salesforce Contact

Tags: wordpress, salesforce

I'm trying to do a relatively simple task by hooking into the Wordpress registration and adding the user that's being registered to a Salesforce db.  When I run the Salesforce db code outside of Wordpress it works flawlessly, but when I test this by registering on my wordpress website, I get an error stating: INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.

Additionally, I receive this error from Wordpress "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent" which doesn't allow me to view the entire object data that's being sent to Salesforce.

This is my code:

```
 $SF_USERNAME = 'test';
 $SF_PASSWORD = 'test';

 define( 'CD_PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );

 require_once (CD_PLUGIN_PATH . 'Toolkit/soapclient/SforceEnterpriseClient.php');
 require_once (CD_PLUGIN_PATH . 'Toolkit/soapclient/SforceHeaderOptions.php');


 function add_user_to_SF($user_id) {
$user = get_userdata($user_id);

 try {
     $mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
     $mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection(CD_PLUGIN_PATH . 'Toolkit/soapclient/enterprise.wsdl.xml');
     $mylogin = $mySforceConnection->login($SF_USERNAME, $SF_PASSWORD);

     print '<pre>'; 
     print_r($mylogin);
     print '</pre>';
     print '<br/><br/>';

$sObject = new stdclass();
$sObject->FirstName = $user->first_name;
$sObject->LastName = $user->last_name;
$sObject->Email = $user->user_email;

//echo "**** Creating the following:\r\n";
$createResponse = $mySforceConnection->create(array($sObject), 'Contact');

$ids = array();
    foreach ($createResponse as $createResult) {
        print_r($createResult);
        array_push($ids, $createResult->id);
    }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
      $errors->add( 'demo_error', __(print_r($_POST),'mydomain') );
      $errors->add( 'demo_error', __($mySforceConnection->getLastRequest(),'mydomain') );
      $errors->add( 'demo_error', __($e->faultstring,'mydomain') );
      return $errors;
}

}

 add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'add_user_to_SF', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a php scope issue.

Adding:
global $SF_USERNAME;
global $SF_PASSWORD;

inside the function fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be missing the security token. It's appended to the end of the password.

This link explains how to generate the token

https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/user_security_token.htm

Comment: Thanks but I fixed the issue using adding globals.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your salesforce account security token with password 
eg. Password - "testing"
    Security Token - "2321njjn32j32"
You need to pass as - "testing2321njjn32j32"

This will work properly.

Comment: @MG1 - while using the above code, were you able to obtain value of **first_name** and **last_name**. I am not able to get any values in them.Help??